# boto3 default session Profile - Access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I need to put the file on s3 using the library based on boto3 (great_expectations), and only have write permissions on a specific profile.

Using `AWS_PROFILE` seems to set the default session's profile, but does not help. To replicate, I ran the code myself and got the same result (AccessDenied):

```py
import boto3
import os
import json

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

bucket = 'my-bucket'
key = 'path/to/the/file.json'
content_encoding="utf-8"
content_type="application/json"

value = json.dumps({'test':'test indeed'})

os.environ['AWS_PROFILE']
>>> mycorrectprofile

boto3.DEFAULT_SESSION.profile_name
>>> mycorrectprofile

s3_object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
s3_object.put(
                    Body=value.encode(content_encoding),
                    ContentEncoding=content_encoding,
                    ContentType=content_type,
                )
```

that results in `AccessDenied`

Now, right after that, I do:

```py
my_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=os.getenv('AWS_PROFILE'))
ss3 = my_session.resource('s3')
r2_s3 = ss3.Object(bucket, key)
```

that runs Smoothly.
What is happening here, and how can I resolve that behavior?

`boto3.__version__ = '1.15.0'`

Comment: My guess is that you need to set `AWS_PROFILE` before importing boto3.

Comment: AWS_PROFILE is set before python runtime. `os.environ['AWS_PROFILE']` just prints the variable

Comment: plus, `boto3.DEFAULT_SESSION.profile_name` shows correct profile

Comment: Try [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) and see what you get.

Comment: yeah, I see it now. We do use `boto3.client("sts").assume_role() ...` in our own code. Is there any way to set it properly for boto3 using env variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223062/discussion-between-philipp-kats-and-jellycsc).